# Query in SQLite with dates

Tags: c#, sqlite

Suppose I have the following student table:

```
id | name | datecreated
------------------------
1  | john | 5/28/2011
2  | peter| 3/15/2011
3  | luke | 5/19/2011
```

What would be my Sql statement if I want to select all students created in the month of May and in the year of 2011, regardless of date.

I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE strftime('%Y', datecreated) = '2011' 
                          AND strftime('%m', datecreated) = '5';
```

Above example taken from:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `strftime('%Y','yourdatefieldvalue')`

This should give you the year part and it takes only string as parameter for the DateTime value (Can't test the query as of now)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     select * from tablename where (datecreated < date('6/1/2011') and 
datecreated >= date('5/1/2011'))
```